# Certificate issue with Apache cordova app in visual studio 2015

Tags: apache, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

Hi I have created a Windows 10 app using Apache Cordova template in Visual Studio 2015, now I need to package the app with client certificate on it if anyone can help me with the same?

Comment: You can refer to [Sign an app package using SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/sign-app-package-using-signtool).

Comment: Hi Elvis this worked thanks for your help :)